# Is this notation equivalent $(\Bbb{Z}_p)^n=\Bbb{Z}_{p}^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

A pretty straightforward , and somewhat embarrasing question concerning notations because I am a bit confused here (trying to study by myself some Abstract Algebra).

> We consider the finite field $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and the vector space $(\Bbb{Z}_p)^n$
>
> Is this notation equivalent $$(\Bbb{Z}_p)^n=\Bbb{Z}_{p}^n$$

In particular, I read that the General Linear Group of matrices of dimension $n$ over the field $\Bbb{Z}_p$, denoted with $GL(n,p)$ is the automorphism group of $\Bbb{Z}_{p}^n$. But I also encountered the first form of the notation, that is, $(\Bbb{Z}_p)^n$ in the same context.

PS Is it obvious that $\Bbb{Z}_{p}^n\neq\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$? I guess these are two questions..In any case, any clarifications will be much appreciated!

Comment: In number theory (and algebra), $\mathbb{Z}_p$ usually denotes the $p$-adic integers; and the finite field with $p$ elements is denoted by $\mathbb{F}_p$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ stands for the cyclic group $C_p$, or for the ring of integers modulo the ideal $(p)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for the additional insight sir! So, if I understood correctly, $GL(n,p)$ are all the invertible matrices with coefficients from $\Bbb{Z}_p$, the field of $p$-adic integers, and because of the dimension of the matrix-amongst other things- ($n\times n$), that is also the group comprised of maps of $\Bbb{Z}_p^n$ to itself..

Comment: No, $GL(n,p)$ means $GL(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ over the finite field, and not over the $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Ahh,ok. I see the difference now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\mathbb{Z}_p)^n$ is just different notation for $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$. And it is also clear that $\mathbb{Z}_p^n \neq \mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ for $n > 1$, since any nonzero element in the former group has order $p$, but the latter group is cyclic of order $p^n$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I suspected as much but in any case thank you for making it clear.